# disable previously selected dropdown option, check both text & id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, jquery-selectors

In a table, **how to loop through all `dropdowns text` & `id` in a table's col, and save them in array. So that I can disable previously selected options**

> Once ***an option is selected, I do not want it to be available again***. *How to check the selected text* of previously *selected options* in the table set that option to disabled on all other dropdowns in the page.

(this question is different from other SO questions since its disabling after checking both `selected text` & `selected value`  inside a table and needs to target the dropdown in the specified column)

```
var allSelectedValuesArray = array();
allSelectedValuesArray.push($("#tblVersions .Model option:selected").text());

var rows = $("body tr",$("#tblVersions")).map(function() { 
return [$("td:eq(0) input:checkbox:checked",this).map(function() { 
  return this.innerHTML;     
}).get()];
}).get();
```

---

```
<table id="tblversions">
 <tbody id="body">
  <tr class="rowcss">
   <td>
    <select class="Manufacturer">
      <option value="1">Toyota </option>
      <option value="2">Honda</option>
      <option value="3">BMW</option>
    </select>
   </td>
   <td>
   <select class="Model"> 
   <!-- If user selects Honda my Ajax populates Honda Models/Cars like below-->
      <option value="1">Accord</option>
      <option value="2">Toyota 2</option>
      <option value="3">Honda 3</option>        
    </select>
   </td>
   </tr>
    <tr class="rowcss">
    <td>
    <select class="Manufacturer">
      <option value="1">Toyota </option>
      <option value="2">Honda</option>
      <option value="3">BMW</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select class="Model">
    <!-- If user selects BMW my Ajax populates BMW models Cars like below-->
      <option value="1">X5 Suv</option>
      <option value="2">318 series Cheap</option>
      <option value="3">540i too expensive!</option>        
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>     
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Your JS doesn't seem related to your HTML (different classes and ids, and the HTML has no input elements). Can you please [edit] your question to give an example of "when the user selects *x* from dropdown *y*, the following should occur..."?

Comment: question is not that much clear

Comment: @nnnnnn I edited the question -  I want to disable any other selected options, how would I do that? *I want to compare both `text` & `value` to be the same*. This is a cascading dropdown - so, In *some cases* if they choose another manufacturer, there could be overlapping Model ID *(but different manufacturer Id)*, for e.g. `Honda could have value 3 = Accord`, while under a diff manufactures `Toyota Value 3 = Camry`, so I need to make sure I check both text and value -- then disable the options

Comment: @JYoThI please see i edited the question to be more clear, I want to check both text & id so I can `disable` any previously selected options

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the second part of your question, but if you want to get text and values for all dropdowns you could do something like this.

```
// Called when any of the dropdowns change
( "#tblversions" ).change(function() {
    var allSelectedValuesArray = [];

    // Search for all selects in the #tblversions
    $("#tblversions select option:selected").each(function() {
        // for each one, push it into the array
        allSelectedValuesArray.push({text:$(this).text(), value:this.value});
    });
});
```

This creates an array of objects in the format {text:"sometext",value:"somevalue"} for each of the dropdowns in the table.

Comment: hi, thanks for that I edited my question., I want to disable any other selected options, how would I do that? *I want to compare both text and value to be the same* In some cases if they choose another manufacturer, there could be overlapping ID, for e.g. Honda could have value 3 = Accord, But Toyota Value 3 = Camry, so I need to make sure I check both text and value